# Shock Absorber - Bus - Not Uniform

Tags: gravity, velocity, kinematics

Imagine a empty bus/lorry travelling at high speed over the "speed brake", why is that only rear seat is heaved relatively high compared to the fron seat?

Answer (score 1):

The rear of the bus normally overhangs the back wheel further than the front of the bus overhangs the front wheel - especially on traditional yellow school buses.

When the bus goes over a bump it pivots around the other set of wheels, the distance you move is the ratio of the distance between the wheels and the distance from your back seat to the front wheel.